# Can I "rotate" and slice in one numpy operation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data like this:

```
[[[1, 2, 3]
  [4, 5, 6]]
 [[7, 8, 9]
  [0, 1, 2]]]
```

and I need to get it into this "shape":

```
[[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
 [[7, 0], [8, 1], [9, 2]]]
```

The best method I have for doing this so far is:

```
for i in range(2):
    pairs = tuple(
        array[i, :, j] for j in range(3)  # ---axis-2-length---
    )
    print(pairs)
```

to produce:

```
([1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6])
([7, 0], [8, 1], [9, 2])
```

While this gets the job done, that's a lot of interpreted Python, especially as these datasets grow. So I was wondering if I could somehow get this done with fancy indexing or transposition or something else my numpy-fu is not yet strong enough to conceive of myself.

Does anyone know how to get this done more elegantly with numpy?

Comment: Start with a (2,3,4) shape array.  The transformation to (2,4,3) should be more more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transposition with [`ndarray.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) will work here.

```
>>> x.transpose(0, 2, 1)
array([[[1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 6]],

       [[7, 0],
        [8, 1],
        [9, 2]]])
```

Comment: Sweetness dawg! Your numpy-fu is indeed strong :)

Comment: @scanny Have waited years to hear that. By the way, if this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course, I just let the answer age a day to see if anyone else wants to weigh in.